# $[G:H]=n$ and a homomorphism $\phi: G \to S_n$. If $\vert G \vert \nmid n!$, then show $\ker(\phi)$ is a nontrivial normal subgroup of $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Here's the problem:

> $H\leqslant G$ has a finite index $n$, so there are $n$ distinct cosets $S = \{ H, x_iH, \ldots, x_{n-1}H \}$ and there exists a homomorphism $\phi: G \to S_n$. An element $g$ belongs to $K = \text{Ker}(\phi)$ iff $gx_iH = x_iH$ for each coset $x_iH$.

Where $S_n$ is the symmetric group with order $n!$. I've already proved $K \leqslant H$ and $[G:K] \big\vert n!$ .

Now I'm asked to prove:

> If $G$ is finite s.t. $|G| \nmid n!$, then prove $K$ is a nontrivial normal subgroup of $G$.

My problem is: we can let $H = G \neq \{e\}$, then $n = 1$ and $|G| \nmid 1!$. Then, since $n = 1$ so $S = \{H\}$, for every $g \in G$ we have $g \in H$, and so $gH = H$, hence $g \in K$ and so $K = G$, but this is a trivial subgroup of $G$.

This is also consistent with the previous two results: $[G:K] = 1$, so $1 \mid 1$, and $K \leqslant H$ because $K = H$.

This would be in contradiction to the statement though, which I'm asked to prove. Where have I gone wrong?

I'm 100% certain I'm not missing any extra premises. My best guess is maybe there's something wrong with having $\phi: G \to S_n$ when $n = 1$? But if $S_1 = \{e\}$, that should still be a valid homomorphism, so I'm really at a total loss.

edit: The only condition I can think of from $|G| \nmid n!$ is that $|G| > n$, which only means $H$ cannot be $\{e\}$.

Comment: "Trivial subgroup" means the subgroup $\{e\}$. $G$ is the "improper" subgroup of $G$. I know some authors say both $G$ and $\{e\}$ are "trivial subgroups", but this is one example where that usage introduces unnecessary complications.

Comment: Ahh, that would make a lot of sense. My professor has been including H = G as a trivial subgroup in lecture, so I guess he could have gotten the problem from a textbook or something. Thank you!

Comment: You can point out the issue when $n=1$ and then prove it in the other cases.